# Pagination on Queue

Tags: javascript, pagination, queue, kafka-consumer-api

I have queue containing 12 records and I have the following parameters with me to paginate,

- length of the queue
- page
- limit

Here I can start from any offset on the queue and read the elements.

From this queue, I have to introduce pagination as for example
page 1 : will return last 10 records and page 2 : will return 2 records.

Note: Here the first page should have the latest record and it iterates only in one manner i.e asc --> desc

If things are puzzled refer this scenario,

1. Consider a queue having max offset of 14 records where 0th position is the oldest data and nth position i.e 14th position having latest data.
2. Here while paginating , 1st page should contain 10 records ( latest ) which is by setting the pointer/offset as 10 and iterating to the last position
3. 2nd page, should start from 0th position but should iterate only 4 records

Could any one help me by providing a psuedocode or in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Update : I have resolved this by the following algorithm,

- get the pointer postition by multiplying page and limit
- then get the max offset from queue
- get the last page by ceil on total records (max offset) divided by per records ( limit )
- check if max offset is less than pointer set, if yes set it to 0 ( eg. starting from last page ) else minus the max offset with pointer postition - this will denote on whether to start from 0 or from next 10 element
- To solve the first page issue , check if its the last page, if yes minus the max offset from (page-1) * limit else set the default limit.
- Declare a counter outside the iterative loop for retreiving the message.
- Now by setting the pointer position, start iterating the queue and on each loop check if the counter matches the limit set if yes exit the loop.

Hope this is clear.